# RESTful POST method when Spring Boot application starts

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest

I need to send a JSON file to API that receives it and processes further. The main issue I'm having is initializing that POST method at application startup. I've created the JSON files, so only that is left over is to activate POST method when the application starts.
I know this is for demonstrating purposes but still haven't found anything like that in Springs documentation.

Basically when the SpringBoot application is run, the first thing that it does is call a post method and sends those JSON files to API. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey, this is a very open question. A good question always is about what you have tried and what did not work. A reference can be found here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello, yes I understand. Somehow I got an answer right away since the question was for a particular problem but not broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a couple of ways:

- Use an `EventListner` Handler (this is what I prefer)
- Create a `Configuration` with a `@PostConstruct` which has the logic - this is something I don't prefer cause it might not always be the one to run post-startup, and in this case, we need `RestTemplate` so we need to think of `Order` of our configuration class, which I think we should tend to avoid as much as possible.

For `EventListener`, you can have the below Component which executes on the `ApplicationStartedEvent`.

```java
@Component
public class AppStartupEventHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppStartupEventHandler.class);

    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationStartUp(ApplicationStartedEvent event) {
        // Have your start business here - or better delegate
        LOGGER.info("This is triggered post startup");
    }

}
```

More details can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.spring-application.application-events-and-listeners) in the official docs

Answer (score 0):

You can use ApplicationReadyEvent listener. Whenever the application will start it will execute one time. Make sure the record / class should be a component.

```
@Component
public record AppStartupRunner() {
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void init() throws IOException {
       // call your post method here
    }
}
```

Comment: Can it be a class instead of a record?

Comment: yes. of course.